# I need to Create 3 Variables from 1 Variable SQL Oracle SAP

Tags: sql, oracle, business-objects

I’m working on creating three variables in the my Universe. The variables are Applications, Operating System, and Physical Location. The problem I’m running into is that all three of these is pulled from the same table and all of them are within the Value.

So the Table `BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP` has the variable Name. I am trying to pull all of the destination instance id's for the operating system when name is equal to `SYSTEMOS`.

My first guest was to use derived tables having each of the three a separate table with the following coding

“Operating System Relationship” Derive Table

```
SELECT
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID 
FROM 
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP 
Where 
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.Name = 'SYSTEMOS'
```

“Physical Location Relationship” Derive Table

```
SELECT
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID 
FROM 
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP 
Where 
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.Name = 'ELEMENTLOCATION'
```

“Applications Relationship” Derive Table

```
SELECT
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID 
FROM 
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP 
Where 
BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.Name = 'APPLICATIONSYSTEMCOMPUTER'
```

However when I try pulling the variable in with the following syntax, only one of the variables will show up in Webi. The others are being nulled I figured out.

App Var

```
Case 
WHEN CI_RELATED_CI.INSTANCEID ="Applications Relationship".DESTINATION_INSTANCEID
Then CI_RELATED_CI.NAME
END
```

Location Var

```
CASE
WHEN CI_RELATED_CI.INSTANCEID = "Physical Location Relationship".DESTINATION_INSTANCEID
THEN CI_RELATED_CI.NAME
END
```

OS Var

```
Case 
WHEN CI_RELATED_CI.INSTANCEID ="Operating System Relationship".DESTINATION_INSTANCEID
Then CI_RELATED_CI.NAME
END
```

I was trying to think of a way to pull all of these into one derived table as separate variables, but so far I have been unsuccessful. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. I'm new so let me know if there is anything I can do to make my questions better.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, though I have an idea, and other's answers have slightly different ideas. Can you add some sample data and expected results to clarify, and explain how `CI_RELATED_CI` fits in? Showing the whole query including joins would be more useful than just the `case`. Also, are your 'derived tables' views?

Answer (score 0):

You can use case like below

```
select Case 
WHEN BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.Name = 'SYSTEMOS'
Then BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID
WHEN BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.Name = 'ELEMENTLOCATION'
Then BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID
When BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.Name = 'APPLICATIONSYSTEMCOMPUTER'
Then BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID
Else 'Ur Comments'
END
from BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP;
```

or Decode

```
select Decode( BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.Name,'SYSTEMOS',BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID,'ELEMENTLOCATION',BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID,'APPLICATIONSYSTEMCOMPUTER',BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP.DESTINATION_INSTANCEID,else) from BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP;
```

Comment: I keep getting an error when i check the syntax "Each calculated column must have an explicit name" for either solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the output

```
create table BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP (name1 varchar2(100),id number);

insert into BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP (name1,id) values('SYSTEMOS',1);

insert into BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP (name1,id) values('ELEMENTLOCATION',2);

insert into BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP (name1,id) values('APPLICATIONSYSTEMCOMPUTER',3);

select Case 
WHEN Name1 = 'SYSTEMOS'
Then id
WHEN Name1 = 'ELEMENTLOCATION'
Then id
When Name1 = 'APPLICATIONSYSTEMCOMPUTER'
Then id
Else id
END
from BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP ;
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

With Decode:

```
select Decode(Name1,'SYSTEMOS',id,'ELEMENTLOCATION',id,'APPLICATIONSYSTEMCOMPUTER',id,id) 
from BMC_CORE_BMC_BASERELATIONSHIP;
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the fact that there are other values are in there as well, but thanks for your ideas!

Comment: still if u r getting error, please share the query with error, so that 'll get to know wt's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly and this is what you want... This is Oracle example where each column has own name or label. You can create table as select - just add create table as before the select and your column names will be the label names:

```
SELECT ename, empno, 
   (CASE deptno WHEN 10 THEN 'Accounting' END) dept10
 , (CASE deptno WHEN 20 THEN 'Research' END)   dept20
 , (CASE deptno WHEN 30 THEN 'Sales' END)      dept30
 , (CASE deptno WHEN 40 THEN 'Operations' END) dept40
FROM scott.emp
ORDER BY ename
/
ENAME   EMPNO   DEPT10      DEPT20     DEPT30     DEPT40
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ADAMS   7876                Research        
ALLEN   7499                           Sales    
BLAKE   7698                           Sales    
CLARK   7782    Accounting          
.....
```